# Return specific status from api retrun in api-platform

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I have a api-platform application. This application call another api. This API returns me JSON response, with a specific status code.

This return is like :

```
[ 
    'id' => [
        'status' => 409,
    ],
    'idBis' => [
        'status' => 200,
    ],
]
```

How can I return again the same status code on api-platform?

I tried to throw Exception with specific code, but like writted [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/#converting-php-exceptions-to-http-errors), one exception return one specific status code.

I want to do something like `throw new \Exception('....', specific status code)`

It's possible?

Comment: Do you use ajax call?

Comment: Yes but status is returned in JSON format

Comment: You get the json response in `.done()` event, right?

Comment: Yes I got it like that

Comment: In `.done()` create `$.post()` request and send data back to api-platform.